# Does a surface in pygame contain more than it can show (load a 40x40 picture on a 20x20 surface)?

Tags: pygame, pygame-surface

If I load a picture of 40x40 pixels on a surface of 20x20 pixels. Does the surface contain all 40x40 pixels even tho it only shows 20x20?

Comment: No, it does not. However you can create a subsurface with [`pygame.Surface.subsurface`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.subsurface)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using a code like this one:

```py
src_surface = pygame.image.load('foo.png')  # size: 40x40px

dest_surf = pygame.Surface((20, 20))
dest_surf.blit(src_surf)
```

Your image will be blit like that:

[image]

In red is the image you want to blit, in black the `Surface` where the image will be blit.

To avoid losing the part of the source surface not in the destination surface, you can use [`pygame.transform.scale`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/transform.html#pygame.transform.scale) like that for example:

```py
src_surf = pygame.image.load('foo.png')

width, height = src_surf.get_size()
width = int(width / 2)
height = int(height / 2)

dest_surf = pygame.transform.scale(src_surf, (width, height))
```

Comment: is there anything outside of the black square gets save to the surface?

Comment: No, the surface only contains the black rectangle. To keep the full image, but only displaying a part of it, you can use [`pygame.Surface.subsurface`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.subsurface).